# Regroup cells of a column in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

I'm new to R and I struggle with this problem :
I have a data frame with proportions and confidence interval (CI) in two groups

| Group | Proportion1 | Confidence Interval1 | Proportion 2 ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Group A | 12 | 10 | ... |
| Group A | 12 | 15 | ... |
| Group B | 20 | 18 | ... |
| Group B | 20 | 22 | ... |

And I need to paste together every two cells of the column Confidence Intervall to obtain this :

| Group | Proportion1 | Confidence Interval1 | Proportion 2 ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Group A | 12 | 10 -15 | ... |
| Group B | 20 | 18 -22 | ... |

I tried to do a "pivot_wider" to split my CI column in two and "unite" the cells together but I have an error message

```
Dataframe %>% 
pivot_wider(col = "Proportion1",
             values_from = "Proportion1" )
```

It's my first time here, so it might not be very clear, sorry for that.

Claire

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~group, ~proportion1, ~confidence_interval1,
  "Group A", 12, 10,
  "Group A", 12, 15,
  "Group B", 20, 18,
  "Group B", 20, 22
)

df |> 
  summarise(
    confidence_interval1 = paste(confidence_interval1, collapse = "-"), 
    .by = c(group, proportion1)
  )
```

Assuming `proportion2` is also constant within groups, you'll want to add `proportion2` to the `.by` argument.

Answer (score 0):

If the values in 'Proportion' columns are single value for each 'Group', we could do a grouping by 'Group' and the Proportion columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
Dataframe %>%
   group_by(Group, across(starts_with("Proportion"))) %>%
   summarise(across(starts_with("Confidence"), ~ str_c(.x, collapse = "-")))
```